# The Registration Authority's response is invalid

Tags: ios, iphone, certificate, mdm

Trying to setup an IOS MDM server and stuck with iphone trying to get the CA certificate from the scep.

I'm using openca as my scep server with a self signed cert.  The scep request from the iphone comes in with parameters : operation=GetCACert&message=EnrollmentCAInstance, but the iphone does not like the response.

Using the sscep tool to test my scep server and i confirm that the CA and RA certificates are being sent out in response to the request.

So can someone shed some light on:
- any special headers (mime type et al) that is required by apple in the scep GetCACert response?
- should the repsonse be a binary response or base64 encoded or any other type of format?
- does the scep have to have any relationship with my mdm server (ie: in terms of common root certificate or the cert used to sign the mdm response to the iphone in the initial profile request)?
- Anyone know of a public scep server i can access to check what a valid GetCACert resopnse looks like?

Answer (score 1):

I worked with iOS SCEP quite long time ago. So, don't remember all details. However, I have answers to several of your questions:

> does the scep have to have any relationship with my mdm server

No. CA/RA are absolutely stand alone entity and doesn't have to have anything in common with mdm.

> Anyone know of a public scep server i can access to check what a valid GetCACert resopnse looks like ?

You can take a look at [jSCEP](https://code.google.com/p/jscep/). It's open source light weight SCEP implementation and I know that it works with iOS.

I would recommend to set it up and check what it will return.